# KD Tree: meaning of `leafsize` parameter

Tags: algorithm, scipy, binary-search-tree, kdtree

I am looking at SciPy's [KD Tree implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree). I am confused by the `leafsize` parameter, which is said to be

> The number of points at which the algorithm switches over to brute-force. Default: 16.

Is this the number of leaves in the BST? If so, that means by default, the KD tree will contain no more than 32 points. This seems unreasonably small, especially for my use case of k=2. Am I interpreting the parameter incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `leafsize` does not control the maximum number of leaves in the tree (which isn't bounded), but rather the number of input points associated with a single leaf in the tree. Consider 64 points being added to a tree. If each point gets associated with a single leaf, you will get a full tree that is seven levels deep and any processing requiring a point will descend these seven levels to find it. Alternatively, if the leafsize is 16, you will get a tree that is only 3 levels deep and each leaf in the tree is associated with 16 points. Processing a point involves descending three levels of the tree and then testing each of the 16 points in the leaf (since they are unordered). This value is can be tuned for performance, and empirically, the best value depends on how exactly the tree is being used.

Conceptually, here is an example of the trees that would be built for different `leafsize` values.

[image: tree construction examples]

You can see how the `leafsize` parameter short-circuits the tree building process in the [scipy source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/build.cxx). This will leave between `leafsize/2` and `leafsize` points unordered in the leafs of the tree.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks so much for this. I guess you had to dig into the source code to figure this out? Or is `leafsize` a standard term in kd-tree literature?

Comment: I think I finally understand what the documentation means by "The number of points at which the algorithm switches over to brute-force.". For a leafsize of 16, the query would need to scan 16 points (in the worst case), which is what the brute-force way does.

Comment: I think this is a pretty standard technique. Take a look at youtube videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLxWtXEbtFE) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoXCr3S00bI) to see some examples building kd-trees with multiple points on the leaves. Often this is referred to as a "stopping criteria" for the tree building process rather than leafsize, especially from more of a machine-learning perspective.

Comment: Thanks Alex; I am just starting to learn this algo as you can see.

Comment: @Alex could you also help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003877/understanding-leafsize-in-scipy-spatial-kdtree ?

Comment: It seems that when using `query_ball_point` the `leafsize` has no effect. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65003877/5025009